# How to calculate matrix roots using the characteristic polynomial using Lua

Tags: matrix, lua, determinants

I am trying to code [eig](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html#btifddh-2) myself, but I am having trouble with calculating the characteristic polynomial `(A-XI)` to get the roots of the matrix. I know how to do that by hand, and it is quite easy. The Lua interpreter cannot just `shove` an additional string in the matrix's elements if I first do not convert them from strings to numbers then concatenate `-X` at the main diagonal.

```
[1-X,   2,   3]
[  4, 5-X,   6]
[  7,   8, 9-X]
```

How can I get the matrix roots without bothering doing any symbolic decompositions and dynamic calculations or compilations?

Comment: What does "shove" mean?

Comment: Well, like when you use `syms X;` in [MatLab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/syms.html) and you are able to create function dependent of `X`. Imagine you need to calculate `det(IX-A)`, where `X` is a `sym` variable and Matlab automatically simplifies this for you. Then you get [an equation like this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=det(%7B+%7B1-x,++2,+++3%7D+,%7B++4,+5-x,+++6%7D+,%7B++7,+++8,+9-x%7D+%7D)).

Comment: When you set it equal to zero you get [the roots](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=det(%7B+%7B1-x,++2,+++3%7D+,%7B++4,+5-x,+++6%7D+,%7B++7,+++8,+9-x%7D+%7D)%3D0).

Comment: It is also possible to convert the matrix to diagonal form using [elementary operations](https://onlinemschool.com/math/library/matrix/elementary_matrix/).

Comment: In other words, you are searching for a Lua library for symbolic calculations and equation solving?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I am wondering how to insert the X and generate the equation.

Comment: I've just googled "Lua + MatLab" and found `scilua.org`.  Another way is to use some interface directly.  Could MatLab read a task from a file (or stdin) and print result to stdout?  If so, you could generate task and get MatLab response using `io.popen`

Comment: Yes. That's correct, but this is for Lua library contribution for matrixes for an open source project and I doubt that the author would like something that relies on a payed product like Matlab ;). You can find the rest of the [library here](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneEduPack/blob/c701fc98ba381aa0c9730211357f50dd3223b9ce/matrix.lua).

Comment: However `scilua.org` sounds promising and it is closer to what I am searching for. Thank you!